# Application stuck on the LaunchScreen without error messages

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, debugging

I work with Xcode Swift 7 and 2.
My application worked very well and after a few modifications, I decided to retest ...
But now she no longer spends LaunchScreen and remains blocked. No error message, nothing in the console, and an application that does not move ...
I returned to arraière and have therefore removed my changes, but nothing to do. She no longer exceeds the LaunchScreen.
The only indication I have is in the "Show the report navigator." The run gets stuck on "Debug" ...
Here is the screen:
[image: debug]

Et voici le screen de mon Warning lors du Building :
[image: Warning Bulding]

**EDIT : Bug found**

I found my bug!
But I do not understand ...
These are TextView this in my initial view problematic. When the text which require an scroll, the application works perfectly, but when the text is too short, the application does not load the view and must surely enter an infinite loop as it does not reference me error ...
Do you have an explanation?

Comment: Pause the debugging session when the application hangs. The stack trace may reveal an endless loop or something similar which prevents the app for completing the launch.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, that you Orientation Settings are interrupted. Probably the info.plist part for UserInterfaceOrientations will gice a hint.

If you say Launch Screen, than i heard about a similar problem. In iOS 9 the LaunchScreen behave did change. 
You can try to reinstall xcode 7, for some people this fixed it. Or Check in your assets the LaunchImage and check if everything is set.

Comment: I do not think it will come from the Xcode software because my other projects still work ...

Comment: do you have a func that changes VC's supported interface orientation?

Comment: are u surr, that you load an viewController? It happens to me yestwrday, that i forgott to set the initialViewController from the storyboard -.- than i had a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

Supported orientations return type is changed from NSUInteger to UIInterfaceOrientationMask. so if your return type is NSUInteger, you'd get that exact message

Comment: thank you, but it does not explain why my application remains on the LaunchScreen?

Comment: Try this: go to plist and there are two supported interface orientations arrays. delete both and replace them by same arrays from a working project

Comment: by plist I meant info.plist

Answer (score -3):

When I run the project with Xcode14.2, the LaunchScreen appears for a moment, immediately becomes a Black Screen, and no Error message appears.

Select Target of Project and check Info information. First, check the Application Screen Manifest, then drop down, check the Scene Configuration, then check the Application Scene Role, drop down further, and you can check the Class Name, Delegate Class Name, Storyboard Name, and Configuration Name.

The reason why it becomes a black screen is that the Class Name must contain UIWindowScreen, the Delegate Class Name must contain $(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate, the Storyboard Name must contain Main, and the Configuration Name must contain the value of Default Configuration.

The fix is ​​to open the Info.plist file in the Navigation Bar Project, check the Application Screen Manifest, then drop down, check the scene configuration, check the application scene role, drop down again, class name, delegate Since class name, storyboard name, configuration name are displayed, enter the above values.

After that, run with clean build of Project and check.

I am a 72-year-old programmer who has studied Swift programming by myself for about 9 years and has released 70 apps, so please guide me as there may be mistakes.[screen shot of info.plist at Target- General](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQkHG.png)